# Double Click Event on charts in a worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, charts, double-click

I have a macro that inserts a worksheet and then inserts 4 charts on to that work sheet. These charts are sized and positioned in such a way that they have a quarter of the screen in that worksheet.

Now I am trying to figure out how to allow the user to double click on one of these charts, which it will enlarge the chart to the full size of the worksheet. When they double click again, it will restore back to its quarter size.

My biggest stumbling block is how to handle and the double click event over the chart in question. I have been able to make it work over the worksheet. But the charts seem to be tricky because they are not there initially. The positioning and sizing is the easy bit. There is help on the web about similar issues, but they assume your chart is a chart and not a worksheet.

Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: You could get the `X,Y` from the mouse cursor, and if it's within the chart's area on the page, trigger the event...But this seems pretty complicated. Perhaps you could add a button to each page that does the same? That macro would be a little easier to program (just a button that says say, "Click to Enlarge/Shrink Chart")?  This might be bordering on an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/)

Comment: To make the double click do anything, you need to use Chart Events. You can read my tutorial about [Chart Events in Microsoft Excel](https://peltiertech.com/chart-events-microsoft-excel/). Combine the double click event with the code in the other answers that resize the charts.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your code for every chart.
Let's assume your charts are `Chart1, Chart2, Chart3, Chart4`.
You can write a Sub to modify the size of your chart and then, call for every `BeforeDoubleClick` event.

```
Private Sub Chart1_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal ElementID As Long, _ 
 ByVal Arg1 As Long, ByVal Arg2 As Long, Cancel As Boolean) 
    Call ChartSize (Chart1)
end Sub
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Would this code example be inserted on the code pane for the worksheet that the charts are on?

Comment: Yes, you should add this code manually for each Chart. It's important to replace `Chart1` with the name of the objects that you create.

Comment: The code will only work if you set up a class module to handle the chart events, as I describe in my tutorial [Chart Events in Microsoft Excel](https://peltiertech.com/chart-events-microsoft-excel/).

Answer (score 0):

Easy to do with single click and change the window zoom rather than the chart size.  You could modify as above for a double click.  You might need to change the zoom values.
If you've already set up your charts you have cell refs for positioning; you need these to deselect the chart so that the next time the user clicks the code runs again.  Otherwise they have to manually click off the chart before selecting it again.

Inside a Module:

```
Sub Setup()
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    Selection.OnAction = "Chart1_Click"
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Activate
    Selection.OnAction = "Chart2_Click"
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 3").Activate
    Selection.OnAction = "Chart3_Click"
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 4").Activate
    Selection.OnAction = "Chart4_Click"
End Sub

Sub Chart1_Click()
    ChartZoom ("Chart 1")
End Sub

Sub Chart2_Click()
    ChartZoom ("Chart 2")
    '  you could select a cell under the chart here; easier than in the sub below
End Sub

Sub Chart3_Click()
    ChartZoom ("Chart 3")
End Sub

Sub Chart4_Click()
    ChartZoom ("Chart 4")
End Sub

Sub ChartZoom(chartRef As String)
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(chartRef).Select 'Activate
    If ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100 Then
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = True
        ' Insert code here to select a range underneath chartRef
    Else
        If ActiveWindow.Zoom <> 100 Then
            ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100
            Range("A1").Select ' <-- Brings back the scroll position to top left
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: That's a interesting approuch. I'll give that a try.